# How Do I Make One Variable Reset to Original Value Before Initial Function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am working on a Choose Your Own Adventure script and in it the player fights a goblin until one of their hit points (var hp) hits 0 or less. If after one round of attacks (the player gets to attack once and the goblin gets to attack once) neither's hp has hit 0 or less the script calls a function that repeats the original round of attacks (but this time both goblin and player have reduced hp and def values). The function continues to loop, of course, until either the player or goblin's hp has hit 0 or less. My problem arose with how I calculated how much damage the player or goblin took every round. Both have an atk variable which subtracts from the opponent's def variable and if the def variable is made to be less than 0 then the absolute value of the def variable is how much is subtracted from either the goblin or player's hp (depending on who attacked who). When the function loops, none of the variables reset. Which is good for every variable except def which I need to reset every round.

My question is: how do I reset the def variable every round to right after the player makes their choice in the armor switch (below)? I need it to happen before the fightLoop() function but not before var armor prompt.

Here is the code:

```
   function getRandomAtk(min,max) {
         return Math.random() *(max-min) + min;
}

//player stats
var player= {
    atk: 1,
    def: 1,
    hp: 10,
    mp: 0,
    block: 1,
    ltn: 0,
    fire: 0, 
    magic: 0,
    ltnDef: 0,
    fireDef:0,
    magDef:0
}
//goblin stats
 var goblin= {
    atk: Math.floor(getRandomAtk(3,6)),
    def: 1,
    hp: 5,
    mp: 0,
    block: 1,
    magDef: 0,
    ltnDef: 0,
    fireDef:0
}
//variable increments
f=0;
g=0;
h=0;
i=0;
j=0;
ff=0;
gg=0;



while(i<=0){
 var begin= prompt("Pick your weapon: sword, staff, or shield").toLowerCase();
 switch(begin) {
         case "sword":
         console.log("You chose the sword. Your Attack is increased by 5. Block is increased by 2");
         player.atk += 5;
         player.block += 2;
         i++;
         break;

     case "staff":
     console.log("You chose the staff. Your Magic is increased by 5. Your MP is increased by 10. You obtained Spell Attack!");
     player.magic += 5;
     player.mp+= 10;
     i++;
     //Spell Attack acquired
     break;


     case "shield":
     console.log("You chose the shield. Your Attack is increased by 2. Your Block is increased by 5");
         player.atk += 2;
         player.block += 5;
         i++;
         break;

    case "stats":
    console.log("Your Stats");
    console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense=" + "1"+ " "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
    continue;

    default:
     console.log("You must make a choice");
     continue;




}
}

 if(begin == "sword") {
 while (f<=0) {
     var sacrifice= prompt("Which weapon do you choose to sacrifice?").toLowerCase();
     switch(sacrifice) {
        case "sword":
        console.log("You cannot do that.");
        break;



        case "staff":
        console.log("You give up the staff. Your Block is increased by 2");
        player.block += 2;
        f++;
        break;

        case "shield":
        console.log("You give up the shield. Your Magic Attack is increased by 2. Your MP is increased by 2");
        player.magic += 2;
        player.mp+= 3;
        f++;
        break;

        case "stats":
        console.log("Your Stats");
        console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense=" + " " + player.def + " "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
        continue;

        default:
        console.log("You must make a choice");
        continue;

    }
}
}

else if(begin=="shield") {
    while(g<=0) {
    var sacrifice2= prompt("Which weapon do you choose to sacrifice?").toLowerCase();
    switch(sacrifice2) {
        case "sword":
        console.log("You give up the sword. Your Magic Attack is increased by 2. Your MP is increased by 2");
        player.magic +=2;
        player.mp+= 3;
        g++;
        break;

        case "staff":
        console.log("You give up the staff. Your Attack is increased by 2. Your Block is increased by 1");
        player.atk += 2;
        player.block +=1;
        g++;
        break;

        case "shield":
        console.log("You cannot do that");
        continue;

    case "stats":
        console.log("Your Stats");
        console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense="+ " " + "1" +" "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
        continue;

        default:
        console.log("You must make a choice");
        continue;

    }
}
}

 else if(begin == "staff") {
    while(h<=0) {
    var sacrifice3= prompt("Which weapon do you choose to sacrifice?").toLowerCase();
    switch(sacrifice3) {
        case "sword":
        console.log("You give up the sword. Your Block is increased by 2");
        player.block +=2;
        h++;
        break;

        case "staff":
        console.log("You cannot do that.");
        continue;


         case "shield":
         console.log("You give up the shield. Your Attack is increased by 2. Your Block is increased by 1");
         player.atk +=2;
         player.block +=1;
         h++;
         break;

         case "stats":
         console.log("Your Stats");
         console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense=" + " " + "1" + " "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
        continue;

        default:
        console.log("You must make a choice");
        continue;

    }
}
}

 while(j<=0){

var armor= prompt("Which armor set do you choose? Magic Robe('robe') or Leather Plate? ('plate')").toLowerCase();
switch(armor) {
    case "robe":
    console.log("You choose the Magic Robe. Your Magic Defense goes up by 3.");
    player.magDef+=3;
    j++;
    break;

    case "plate":
    console.log("You choose the Leather Plate. Your Defense goes up by 3.");
    player.def+=3;
    j++;
    break;

     case "stats":
     console.log("Your stats");
     console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense=" + " " + player.def + " "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
     continue;

     default:
     console.log("You must make a choice.");
     continue;
 }
 }





 var fight= alert("A goblin attacks you!");

 fightLoop();

 function fightLoop() {
 while(ff<=0) {
  var fight2= prompt("What do you do? 'Attack' or 'Block'? or 'Spell      Attack(spell)'?").toLowerCase();
 switch(fight2) {
    case "attack":
     console.log("You Attack the goblin!");
     goblin.def-=player.atk;

     if(goblin.def<0) {
         goblin.hp-=Math.abs(goblin.def);
         console.log("You dealt"+ " " + Math.abs(goblin.def) + " "+ "damage!");
        if(goblin.hp<=0) {
            console.log("The goblin is slain!");
            ff++;
             gg++;
         }

         else if(goblin.hp>=0) {
            ff++;
        }
    }

     else {
         console.log("You did 0 damage!");
     ff++;
     }
     break;

    case "spell":
     if(begin=="staff"){
         console.log("You cast a Spell Attack!");
         goblin.magDef-=player.magic;

         if(goblin.magDef<0) {
             goblin.hp-= Math.abs(goblin.magDef);
             console.log("You dealt" + " " + Math.abs(goblin.magDef) + " " + "damage!");
            if(goblin.hp<=0) {
                console.log("The goblin is slain!");
                ff++;
                gg++;
            }

            else {
                ff++;
            }
        }

        else {
            console.log("You did 0 damage!");
            f++;
        }
}

     else {
         console.log("You cannot use magic.")
     }
    continue;

    case "block":
    console.log("You choose to Block the goblin's next Attack!");
    ff++;
    break;

     case "stats":
     console.log("Your Stats");
     console.log("Attack=" + " " + player.atk + " " + "Defense=" + " " + player.def + " "+ "HP=" + " " + player.hp+ " " + "MP=" + " " + player.mp+ " " +"Block=" + " " + player.block + " " +"Lightning Atk="  + " " + player.ltn + " " + "Fire Atk="+ " " + player.fire + " "+ "Magic Atk=" + " " + player.magic + " " + "Lightning Def="+ " " + player.ltnDef + " "+ "Fire Def=" + " " + player.fireDef + " " + "Magic Def=" + " " + player.magDef);
    continue;

    case "goblin stats":
    console.log("Goblin Stats");
    console.log("Attack=" + " " + goblin.atk+ " " + "Defense="+ " "+ goblin.def+ " "+ "HP="+ " "+ goblin.hp+ " "+ "MP="+ " "+ goblin.mp+ " " + "Block"+ " "+ goblin.block+ " "+ "Magic Defense"+ " "+ goblin.magDef)
    continue;

    default:
    console.log("You must make a choice.");
     continue;
}
}

if (gg>0) {
    console.log("You won the game! Congratulations!")
}

else {
var retaliate= alert("The Goblin Attacks you!");

if (fight2== "block") {
    player.def+=player.block;
    player.def-= goblin.atk;
        if(player.def<0) {
            console.log("You blocked the Attack!");
            player.hp-=Math.abs(player.def);
            console.log("The Goblin did"+ " "+ Math.abs(player.def)+ " "+ "Damage!");

            if(player.hp<=0) {
                console.log("The Goblin defeated you! You died.");
                console.log("Game Over.");


            }


        }


        else {
            console.log("The goblin did 0 damage!");
        }
}

else {
    player.def-=goblin.atk;
        if(player.def<0) {
            player.hp-=Math.abs(player.def);
            console.log("The Goblin did"+ " "+ Math.abs(player.def)+ " "+ "Damage!");
                if(player.hp<=0) {
                    console.log("The Goblin defeated you! You died");
                    console.log("Game Over.");

                }


        }
        else {
            console.log("The Goblin did 0 damage!");
        }
}
}
}

if (goblin.hp>=0) {
    ff-=1;
    fightLoop();
```

}

Comment: You should include all of your code, for context. I'm having a hard time understanding the flow of your game without it.

Comment: @JonathanBrooks Disagree. Users, especially newer ones, should not be actively encourages to post the entirety of their code. By all means ask "what does that function do?" but don't get them to post everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add variables to the player "class" to represent the max values for each stat:

```
var player= {
  def: 1,
  max_def: 10,
  hp: 10,
  max_hp: 10,
  ...
}
```

And if you need to reset something in an encounter set the current value back to the max value :

```
player.def = player.max_def;
```

Comment: That would work in this particular case (because right now there is only one if statement choice that would raise the value of def) but I was looking for a way to return the value of a variable back to a certain point on the code- not to a max. The reason being if I wanted to put in several other if/else statements that could further influence the variable def (like other armor choices). And if the player selected an armor choice that raised def less than the best armor choice (in that it raises def the most), I would want def to cycle back to that point.

Comment: max_def wouldn't represent the maximum defense possible. It would represent the maximum defense the player can currently have. Adding or changing armour would increase or decrease the max_def stat rather than the regular def stat.

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but you could reset the armor value by just defining the starting value before the incrementation

```
var player= {
def: 1,
hp: 10
}

var armor= prompt("Do you choose the Leather plate armor set? If yes, type ('plate')").toLowerCase();

switch(armor) {

case "plate":
console.log("You choose the Leather Plate. Your Defense goes up by 3.");
player.def=1;
player.def+=3;
j++;
break;

default:
console.log("You must make a choice.");
continue;
}

var fight= alert("A goblin attacks you!");

fightLoop();
```

Or just add some input parameters to your fightLoop function.